# About IP 0.0.0.0 in Django

Tags: django, ip

We've got a server over which we're running a Django powered site. Since we want to test the site, we're using Django's build-in development server (i.e `runserver`).  But I'm curious about the ip of the following command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

It results in a running site we can visit using server's ip remotely.
But when using `127.0.0.1` instead:

```
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:80
```

No one can visit the site with the sever's ip from another pc.

So why? What does `0.0.0.0` exactly means (Google says it's the default route) ?  Why can't `127.0.0.1:80` be accessed remotely?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`0.0.0.0:80` is a shortcut meaning "bind to all IP addresses this computer supports". `127.0.0.1:80` makes it bind only to the "lo" or "loopback" interface. If you have just one [NIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_interface_controller) with just one IP address, you could bind to it explicitly with, say, `192.168.1.1:80` (if `192.168.1.1` was your IP address), or you could list all the IPs your computer responds to, but `0.0.0.0:80` is a shortcut for that.

Comment: To add to the answer, this won't work on Windows. Refer [here](https://superuser.com/a/536198/1789174)

Answer (score 12):

127.0.0.1 is the [loopback interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback), also known as `localhost`; this is an address that is only accessible from the same computer, as nothing actually goes over the network. 0.0.0.0  means "listen on all interfaces", and thus will listen for connections on all IP addresses that machine has (likely only one).

Answer (score 2):

127.0.0.1 is the local (loopback) ip, not the ip of that computer on the network. To access a server across the network, you'll need to know its' network ip

Comment: thanks adam. but is 0.0.0.0:80 a must to provide the access for other clients?