# I'm not able to access the Django server running on a VM from a windows host

Tags: linux, django, windows, ubuntu, virtual-machine

So I am learning Django and instead of trying to set everything up on Windows, I set up a Ubuntu 14.04 Server VM and set everything up there. I've set the Network mode to Bridged. I am able to SSH into the VM and everything works fine on that end. I followed this guide: https://github.com/makrandgupta/pyladies-django-workshop and was able to get through the installation process. I run the final command and the program tells me that the server is up and running. When I try to access the guest's IP from my browser on my host, I just get a Connection Refused Error. I had tried it with another linux installation and there I was able to access the website from the browser inside the guest but not from the host. I thought it would be an issue with the distro so switched to Ubuntu Server and having the same issue with it.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're able to SSH to the guest from the host, then it's likely to be a firewall rule blocking access or simply that you don't have Apache running.

Comment: Voting to migrate to ServerFault

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I installed Lynx and I can browse the website from it at localhost:8000

Comment: Yes, but firewalls usually operate on external traffic. You also didn't mention that your website it running on port 8000, so you'll need to open that port if you have a firewall running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are accessing the site from another server, then `python manage.py runserver` will not work. You could specify the actual ip of the server, or use `0.0.0.0`.

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

See the question [About IP 0.0.0.0 in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621457/about-ip-0-0-0-0-in-django) for more info.

Comment: Just found this answer on another forum and was about to post it here. This is the answer for me. Thanks a lot!