# "Can't connect to ('0.0.0.0', 5000)" when trying to deploy Django app to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a Django app to Heroku. I get following error after I run `heroku local` command and go to `http://0.0.0.0:5000`

```
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '0.0.0.0:5000'. You may need to add '0.0.0.0' to ALLOWED_HOSTS
```

However, allowed hosts is already set up like this. My setting.py file:

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
if cwd == '/app' or cwd[:4] == '/tmp':
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')
    }
    #honorowanie naglowka xforwardedproto dla request.is_secure()
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

    #zezwolenie na wszystkie naglowki hosta
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['0.0.0.0']

    #konfiguracja zasobow statycznych
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

Initially I had allowed hosts set to `['*']`, but it didn't work as well.

I am using gunicorn and also tried restarting it using `pkill gunicorn`, but that didn't help.

Is there a better way to restart gunicorn or maybe another solution to the problem?

Comment: What dou you mean with "and go to http://0.0.0.0:5000"?  Since 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP address...

Comment: When I run `heroku local`, the line `[2018-06-22 22:33:34 +0200] [1997] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1997)` appears in the terminal. I just go to the link from this line.

Comment: That means it binds to all IPs on this machine, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621457/about-ip-0-0-0-0-in-django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: I already had another ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py, whis is there by default. I had to set this to `['0.0.0.0']` and delete the other one.