# Cannot route traffic with Minikube + ingress + Django

Tags: django, kubernetes-ingress, minikube, kubernetes-service

In my local development setup, I'm using Django as the webserver (a-la `python manage.py runserver 8000`) and I'm able to `kubectl port-forward <django_pod> 8000` my traffic to my local dev machine so I can interact with my site by browsing to `http://localhost:8000/testpage`. I've configured my `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to include `localhost` to enable this.

However, I'd like to avoid using `port-forward` and go the more proper route of running my traffic through the Kubernetes ingress controller and service. **On the same Minikube cluster, I have ingress configured to point certain traffic urls to a very rudimentary `nginx` pod to confirm that my ingress+service+pod networking is working properly.** All other urls should route to my Django app. The only difference is the nginx traffic is all on port 80.

In my ingress controller logs, I can see the traffic being sent to the k8s service for my Django app: 
`192.168.64.1 - [192.168.64.1] - - [22/Nov/2019:03:50:52 +0000] "GET /testpage HTTP/2.0" 502 565 "-" "browser" 24 0.002 [default-django-service-8000] [] 172.17.0.5:8000, 172.17.0.5:8000, 172.17.0.5:8000 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.000 502, 502, 502 aa2682896e4d7a2052617f7d12b1a02b`

When I look at the Django logs, I don't see any traffic hitting it.

My ingress `servicePort` is `8000`, the `django-service` port is `8000` (I've just let it default to `ClusterIP`), the pod's `spec.containers.ports.containerPort` is `8000`, and the process has been set to listen on port `8000` as I mentioned before.

When I check `kubectl get endpoints`, it correctly shows me an endpoint is connected on port 8000 (and it correctly changes to the new pods' IPs when I restart them).

I've used the following guides to try to debug:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/
- https://medium.com/@ManagedKube/kubernetes-troubleshooting-ingress-and-services-traffic-flows-547ea867b120

My guess is it might be a problem with `ALLOWED_HOSTS` but I added a `*` wildcard to the list and it's still not working.

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Could you post your ingress YAML? Also what version of Minikube and kubernetes are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instruct the server to listen on all interfaces by running `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<port>`.

Django's runserver listens on the local loopback interface (localhost/127.0.0.1) by default so, if you run `python manage.py runserver 8000`, you can can only reach the server on port 8000 from the machine on which the server is running.

There is a lot of documentation around this, but here are just a couple examples:

- [About IP 0.0.0.0 in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621457/about-ip-0-0-0-0-in-django)
- http://www.holeintheceiling.com/blog/2012/06/21/django-and-runserver-0-0-0-0/