# Django, RestAPI, Microsoft Azure, website, virtual machine, ubuntu

Tags: python, django, azure, ubuntu

I have developed a website and REST api using Django and Django REST Framework. On local machine they are working perfectly so my next step is trying to publish it on remote server. I chose Microsoft Azure.

I created a virtual machine with Ubuntu server 18.04 and installed everything to run my project there. While I run it locally on virtual machine it's working perfectly, at localhost:8000; my website and rest-api are showing.

Now I want it to publish to the world so it can be accessed under the IP of my virtual machine or some different address so everybody can access it. I was looking through azure tutorials on Microsoft website and google, but i cannot find anything working.

I don't want to use their Web App solution or Windows Server. It needs to be working with Ubuntu Virtual machine from Azure. Is it possible to do and if yes then how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Reading your question, it's difficult to ascertain what your actual issue is, just a general statement about being unable to access it remotely (I'd suggest editing to include more specifics). Maybe it's a firewall issue on your VM? Maybe it's a Network Security Group rule on your inbound port(s) for your VM? In that case, this really isn't a programming question; rather, more of a general Linux question.

Comment: My questions is what to do in Django files and microsoft azure, so it can be accessed outsite localhost, for example i go to IPOFMACHINE.COM from my phone and i can see my website

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, Azure has Network Security Groups and Inbound/outbound network rules for VMs. Have you verified that you're allowing inbound traffic on 80/443? Have you placed your VM into a VNet (which would limit access)? Other than that, this is going to fall into the Django or Ubuntu area for changing settings. But you haven't shared any details of any settings, so right now this would be a guessing game. As such, this question is currently off-topic as "too broad." Totally ok to post a question like this, but it really needs more detail; please edit accordingly.

Comment: Dude, like i said in my question, I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO, that's where i am looking for guidance since i cannot find anything that's working on google, so i am looking for tutorial written by users here or a link how to get from running django project with localhost addres to run it with public domain

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic as well. I'm trying to help, but every response by you is about you being unable to find a tutorial, without providing any further detail. I just did a quick search and found lots of info about deploying Django to Ubuntu. Have you edited your `settings.py` to add your vm's IP address (you've mentioned nothing about that)? There's really nothing more I can offer at this point and won't be commenting any more. Feel free to edit your question (not posting additional info in comments).

Answer (score 0):

1. (Optional) Set your web application listen publicly on 80 port for http or 443 port for https. You may refer to: [About IP 0.0.0.0 in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1621457/about-ip-0-0-0-0-in-django)
2. In Ubuntu OS, if firewall is enabled, you need to open port 80 and 443, so that others can access your server.
3. In Azure portal, if NSG is enabled, you need to add inbound rules for 80 and 433.
4. (Optional) Buy a domain, and add an `A` record to your VM's IP. In this way, people would be able to access your website via friendly URL.